# New function by adding two functions

Tags: julia

Is it possible to create a new function from the addition of two other functions in Julia? I want to do something like this:

```
function quadratic(x)
  return x^2
end

function cubic(x)
  return x^3
end

f::Function = quadratic + cubic
# such that f(x) returns x^2 + x^3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is the less magic solution which is `f(x) = quadratic(x) + cubic(x)`

Comment: Unless there is some special need not declared in the question this seems the obvious solution...

Comment: Or even `lifted(op, f, g) = x -> op(f(x), g(x))` or something like that, and then `lifted(+, quadratic, cubic)`.

Answer (score 3):

Every function<sup>[1]</sup> in Julia is a multimethod and can be extended after-the-fact. If we try to do `quadratic + cubic`, we get a message

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching +(::typeof(quadratic), ::typeof(cubic))
```

This isn't saying there will *never* be a way to make that work; it's saying nobody has bothered to do it *yet*. Let's write a version that works on functions.

```
# Extend the existing +, don't shadow it
import Base.+

+(f::Function, g::Function) =
    (args...; kwargs...) -> f(args...; kwargs...) + g(args...; kwargs...)
```

Now we can write

```
fn = quadratic + cubic
println(fn(10)) # 1100
```

---

[1] Technically, there are a handful of low-level bootstrapping functions that are deep magic and can't be extended, but `+` is not one of those.

Comment: I suppose it's because in general two Functions f and g won't take the same inputs (by number or type) or have addable outputs, so this Function-adding method will usually return a function that can only error. Julia doesn't have function types with argument and output type information, something like Function{{Number}, Number}. I read that Go has these, and I don't really know Go but my guess is that function types are more feasible in a language with concrete argument types, no multimethods, and limited generic functions.

Comment: @BatWannaBe I don't know Go terribly well (only used it for a handful of small tasks), but I'd be amazed if it had something that sophisticated. One of the main gripes I have heard time and time again with Go is the lack of type generics. While it's possible they special cased function types to do something awesome with `+`, it would surprise me greatly.

Comment: Here's a link to an example of a Go function type with a very short description. This example's type is named `Operator` and describes any function with 1 float64 input and a float64 output, and it is used to annotate an argument of a higher order function `Map(op Operator, a []float64) []float64`
https://yourbasic.org/golang/function-pointer-type-declaration/

Comment: While this solution will work, it is type piracy, which is not recommended practice: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Avoid-type-piracy